# Data is not fetched after redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have the following actions in my vuejs app vuex store:

```
 import { HTTP } from '@/services/http'
import router from '@/router'

export const actions = {
  loginUser ({ commit }, params) {
    HTTP.post('v1/login.json', { email: params.email, password: params.password })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.token)
      router.push({name: 'Hello'})
    }).catch(error => {
      commit('SET_LOGIN_ERROR', error.response.data.error)
    })
  },

  myAccount ({ commit }, params) {
    HTTP.get('v1/my_account.json', { headers: {'Authorization': 'Token token=' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')} })
    .then(response => {
      commit('SET_USER', response.data)
    })
  },

  logout ({ commit }, params) {
    HTTP.delete('v1/logout.json', { headers: {'Authorization': 'Token token=' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')} })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
      commit('SET_USER', {})
    })
  }
}
```

and the following navigation component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{user.first_name}}
    {{user.last_name}}
    {{user.email}}
    <button v-on:click="logout()" v-if="Object.keys(user).length !== 0">Logout</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    name: 'hello',
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['myAccount', 'logout'])
    },

    beforeMount: function () {
      if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
        this.myAccount()
      }
    },

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['user'])
    }
  }
</script>
```

This component is mounted inside App.Vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navigation></navigation>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Navigation from './components/Navigation.vue'

  export default {
    components: { Navigation },
    name: 'app'
  }
</script>
```

The problem is following:

1. I visit login page and type valid email and password.
2. I'm redirected to root path. Naviagation component should retrieve user data from api but it does not do that.
3. When I refresh page with F5 Navigation component gets data properly.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that the `beforeMount` hook is getting fired before the `loginUser` action has set the `access_token`. You could dispatch `myAccount` in the `then` callback of the `loginUser` action's post request.

Answer (score 0):

Your access_token is probably not getting set and the component is going into beforeMount before and then when you reload, you already have the access token in localstorage so it's working.
`localStorage.setItem` is synchronous but you probably can get around this with a promise. I haven't tested this but it should work.

```
setItem: function (key, value) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    });
}
```

and then you call this function like so inside your resolved api login call

```
setItem('access_token', response.data.token).then(function () {
    return router.push({name: 'Hello'})
});
```